# Python: How remove duplicates words in string that are not next each other?

Tags: python, string

In the example below, I need to remove only the third "animale" which is alone in the string. How can I do that?

```
a = 'animale animale eau toilette animale'
```

Second "animale": dont remove

Third "animale":  remove

Comment: You need to remove only the occurences at the end of the strings ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber if I understand the title correctly, only occurrences that are not adjacent to each other are to be removed.

Comment: @AdrienLeber: that's correct! duplicate occurrences that are not adjacent to each other are to be removed

Comment: what if you have `animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau`? should the first `eau` be removed?

Comment: What about `animale animale eau eau toilette eau eau`? What gets removed here? Anything?

Comment: What about "animale eau animale animale" - do we remove the first animale? Or do we take the first animale as the first occurrence and therefore keep it, and also keep the second two because they are next to each other and therefore "safe"

Comment: Adam, this is a good question. Actually this scenario will not gonna happen.

Comment: Sixhobbits, in  "animale eau animale animale" need to remove the first animale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
from collections import defaultdict

def remove_no_adjacent_duplicates(string):
    position = defaultdict(list)
    words = string.split()
    for i,w in enumerate(words):
        position[w].append(i)
    for w,pos_list in position.items():
        adjacent = set()
        for i in range(1,len(pos_list)):
            if pos_list[i-1] +1 == pos_list[i]:
                adjacent.update( (pos_list[i-1],pos_list[i]) )
        if adjacent:
            position[w] = adjacent
        else:
            position[w] = pos_list[:1]
    return " ".join( w for i,w in enumerate(words) if i in position[w] )

print( remove_no_adjacent_duplicates('animale animale eau toilette animale') )
print( remove_no_adjacent_duplicates('animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau' ) )
print( remove_no_adjacent_duplicates('animale eau toilette animale eau eau' ) )
print( remove_no_adjacent_duplicates('animale eau toilette animale eau de eau de toilette' ) )
```

output

```
animale animale eau toilette
animale animale toilette eau eau
animale toilette eau eau
animale eau toilette de
```

explanation

first I record the position of each word in the `position` dict, then I proceed to check if there is any adjacent position among them for each word, if there is any I save both it in a set, when that is finished if any is found I exchange the list of position for this set of adjacent otherwise remove all the saved position except for the first, and finally reconstruct the string

Comment: Copperfield, thank you for your function! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "animale animale eau toilette animale"

words = a.split()

cleaned_words = []
skip = False
for i in range(len(words)):
    word = words[i]
    print(word)
    if skip:
        cleaned_words.append(word)
        skip = False
    try:
        next_word = words[i+1]
        print(next_word)
    except IndexError:
        break
    if word == next_word:
        cleaned_words.append(word)
        skip = True
        continue
    if word not in cleaned_words:
        cleaned_words.append(word)

print(cleaned_words)
```

Quite an ugly, rough solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Actually wait, it doesn't really in more complicated cases such as "animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau". OP needs to provide more criteria for what to remove, currently the first occurrence of "eau" wouldn't be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dartmouth!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to remove any occurrences of words that are duplicates but not adjacent. I think this solution works for that:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def remove_duplicates(s):
    result = []
    word_counts = defaultdict(int)
    words = s.split()
    # count the frequency of each word
    for word in words:
        word_counts[word] += 1
    # loop through all words, and only add to result if either it occurs only once or occurs more than once and the next word is the same as the current word.
    for i in range(len(words)-1):
        curr_word = words[i]
        if word_counts[curr_word] > 1:
            if words[i+1] == curr_word:
                result.append(curr_word)
                result.append(curr_word)
                word_counts[curr_word] = -1    # mark as -1 so as not to add again
                i += 1       # skip the next word by incrementing i manually because it has already been added
            # if there are only two occurrences of the word left but they aren't adjacent, add one and mark the counts so you don't add it again.
            elif word_counts[curr_word] < 3:
                result.append(curr_word)
                word_counts[curr_word] = -1    # mark as -1 so as not to add again
            # not adjacent but more than 2 occurrences left so decrement number of occurrences left
            else:
                word_counts[curr_word] -= 1 
        elif word_counts[curr_word] == 1:
            result.append(curr_word)
            word_counts[curr_word] = -1
    # Fix off by one error by checking last index
    if word_counts[words[-1]] == 1:
        result.append(words[-1]) 
    return ' '.join(result)
```

I think this works for any case where the repeated words aren't adjacent including @Dartmouth's example of 'animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau'.

Sample inputs and outputs:

```
 Inputs                                               Outputs
 =============================================       =========================================
'animale animale eau toilette animale'                  ---->     'animale animale eau toilette'
'animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau'          ---->     'animale animale toilette eau eau'
'animale eau toilette animale eau eau'                  ---->     'animale toilette eau eau' 
'animale eau toilette animale eau de eau de toilette'   ---->     'animale toilette eau de'
'animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau compte'   ---->     'animale animale toilette eau eau compte'
```

Comment: Hi Gowrath! Thank you for the answer! On the third and fourth examples, I need to keep at least one of the duplicate words: 'animale eau toilette animale eau eau'                  ---->     'animale toilette eau eau'

Comment: 'animale eau toilette animale eau de eau de toilette'   ---->     ''animale eau toilette de ''

Comment: @Ailton Fixed. I can't make this code neater until you explain your requirements better but this works. I am assuming, in the last two cases, you need to keep at least one of the duplicate words but which specific one doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much Gowrath! That's exactly what I need!

Comment: @Ailton Made a slight adjustment. Forget the off by one error at the end.

Comment: Gowrath, I made a fix on this line: result.append(words[-1])

Comment: And this one (line 25): cur_word to curr_word - Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This one works for both:

`'animale animale eau toilette animale'`

and

`'animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau'`

Here's the code:

```
from collections import Counter


def cleanup(words):
    splitted = words.split()
    counter = Counter(splitted)
    more_than_one = [x for x in counter.keys() if counter[x] > 1]
    orphan_indexes = []

    before = True

    for i in range(len(splitted)):
        if i == len(splitted):
            break
        if i > 0:
            before = splitted[i] != splitted[i-1]
        if i+1 <= len(splitted):
            try:
                after = splitted[i] != splitted[i+1]
            except IndexError:
                after = True
        if before and after:
            if splitted[i] in more_than_one:
                orphan_indexes.append(i)

    return ' '.join([
        item for i, item in enumerate(splitted)
        if i not in orphan_indexes
    ])


print cleanup('animale animale eau toilette animale')
print cleanup('animale animale eau toilette animale eau eau')
```

Result:

```
animale animale eau toilette
animale animale toilette eau eau
```

Comment: Hi turkus! for this scenario a = 'animale eau toilette animale eau de eau de toilette' the function not worked.